# Phobos/Ruby-Kafka API call timeout configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-kafka, phobos, ruby-kafka

I'm working on a project that uses Phobos to consume messages from Kafka. As part of migrating the project to new infrastructure, i've started seeing a significant increase in timeouts when Phobos makes API calls to Kafka. It isn't 100% of the time, but it is significant. I'm troubleshooting with infrastructure engineers to understand why these calls are taking so much longer on the new infrastructure.

In the mean time, i'm looking to see if there is a way to increase the timeouts for the API requests that are made as part of Phobos/Ruby-Kafka library. Some example requests that are occuring:

```
Sending join_group API request
[join_group] Waiting for response
[join_group] Timed out while waiting for response
```

There are properties for `session_timeout` and `connect_timeout` but those seem to only be related to the connection to Kafka itself.  But these individual API calls that are made while the project is running are timing out significantly sooner than these values.

Answer (score 2):

ex-contributor to ruby-kafka here.

First of all, please keep in mind that ruby-kafka is no longer supported or maintained. This project has been superseded by https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby/

It means you might have found an edge case that is a bug or an issue. Aside from that, this particular timeout usually occurs for remote clusters where the latency is much higher. The default socket_timeout for ruby-kafka was 20 seconds but you may try to increase it and connect_timeout to a higher value.

If that does not help and/or cluster is not over the network one, it may also indicate permission problems (though less likely).

If anything, I would recommend you to try out one of the other frameworks that are C librdkafka-based, like https://github.com/karafka/karafka, or try to connect and consume from this cluster by using https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby/ itself. You will not get much help for ruby-kafka issues if this one turns out to be related to it.

Comment: Thanks.  We're still investigating to figure out why we've only started seeing this issue on the new infrastructure.  We've been using Phobos on all of these projects for years with no issues.  

It is a good call out that Phobos is using a deprecated library for its Kafka integration though.

Comment: It may be you are using a different Kafka version. ruby-kafka is not being updated for a longer period of time, thus its compatibility with newer API versions will deteriorate. Both things I mentioned above (rdkafka-ruby and karafka) are using the most recent C driver for Kafka and receive frequent upgrades. ruby-kafka has critical issues at this stage and is absolutely not recommended for production usage anymore.